# Understanding definition of Periodicity of Markov chain

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, definition, markov-chains

Consider the following example that is used to understand the definition of periodicity property.

> [image]
>
> [image]

[image]

Why does it says that:

starting in state $1$, it is possible for the process to enter state $1$ only at times $2, 4, . . . ,$ so state $1$ has period $2$.
The reason is that the player can break even (be neither winning nor losing) only at times $2, 4, . . . ,$ which can be verified by calculating $p_{11}^{(n)}$ for all $n$ and noting
that $p_{11}^{(n)} = 0$ for $n$ odd.

I do not understand.

First off isn't $p_{11}^{(n)} = 0$ for all $n$, not just $n$ odd?

By definition $p_{11}^{(n)}=p\{X_{t+n}=1|X_t=1\}$

From the matrix **P**, $p_{11}^{(n)}=p\{X_{t+n}=1|X_t=1\}=0$, hence the probability will always be zero, no?

Comment: an odd number plus an odd number is an even number. But you can return to $1$ by wining one and losing 1.

Comment: @Phicar how is that 'you can return to 1 by wining one and losing 1' ?

Comment: Well the gambling is wining $1$ with probability $p$ and losing $1$ with probability $1-p$ so you can win or loose.

Comment: @Phicar why does that imply returning to state 1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"First off isn't $p_{11}^{(n)} = 0$ for all $n$, not just $n$ odd?"

No.  $\ p_{11}^{(2)}= p\left(1-p\right)\ne 0\ $.  I suspect you're confusing state $0$ with state $1$.  It *is* true that $\ p_{00}^{(n)}=  1\ $ for all $\ n\ $, so that state is aperiodic.

It is *not* correct that $\ p\{X_{t+n}=1|X_t=1\}=0\ $.
$$ p\{X_{t+n}=1|X_t=1\}=\begin{bmatrix}0&1&0&0
\end{bmatrix}\boldsymbol{\mathrm{P}}^n\begin{bmatrix}0\\1\\0\\0
\end{bmatrix}\ ,$$
and
$$ \boldsymbol{\mathrm{P}}^2=\begin{bmatrix}
1&0&0&0\\
1-p&p\left(1-p\right)&0&p^2\\
\left(1-p\right)^2&0&p\left(1-p\right)&p\\
0&0&0&1\end{bmatrix}\ .$$
It is the entry in the *second* row and *second* column of $\ \boldsymbol{\mathrm{P}}^n\ $that is $\ p_{11}^{(n)}\ $.

Comment: Thank you, just one question I haven't seen this $p\{X_{t+n}=1|X_t=1\}=\begin{bmatrix}0&1&0&0
\end{bmatrix}\boldsymbol{\mathrm{P}}^n\begin{bmatrix}0\\1\\0\\0
\end{bmatrix}$ before could you explain? specially the **P**$^n$, why is there ?

Comment: @Al t. I'm not sure what it is that you need to be explained.   Do you know that $\ p_{ij}^{(n)}\ $ is just the entry in the $\ i^{\mathrm{th}}\ $ row and $\ j^{\mathrm{th}}\ $ column of $\ \boldsymbol{\mathrm{P}}^n\ $? Do you need it to be explained why $\ p_{ij}^{(n)} = p\left\{X_{t+n}=j \left\vert X_t=i\right.\right\}\ $, or are you taking *that* to be a *definition*?

Comment: Yes I understand that $^{()}_{}$  is just the entry in the  $^{th}$  row and  $^th$  column of  $^ $. Yes the definition I am using is indeed $\ p_{ij}^{(n)} = p\left\{X_{t+n}=j \left\vert X_t=i\right.\right\} $. I wanted the explanation of $\begin{bmatrix}0&1&0&0 \end{bmatrix}\boldsymbol{\mathrm{P}}^n\begin{bmatrix}0\\1\\0\\0 \end{bmatrix}$ but never mind I've just understand it ^ .^